# More brackets than necessary?

Tags: logic

$(O(p \land \neg p))\rightarrow Oq$

Consider the formula above: does it include more brackets than necessary? I want it to say if it ought to be the case that both $p$ and $\neg p$ then it ought to be the case that $q$ ('$O$' is the ought operator and '$\rightarrow$' is the material conditional).

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: You've interpreted the formula correctly. As to whether it contains more brackets than necessary, this is a matter of your conventions for brackets. In practice, just like in arithmetic expressions, people usually use parentheses (brackets) for clarity, without worrying too much about precise conventions.

Comment: I don’t know of any convention that would require the antecedent to have a second pair of brackets.

Comment: @Pdubya_24 Well, one could imagine a convention that $\rightarrow$ binds more strongly than $O$, so that $O(p\land \lnot p)\rightarrow Oq$ would be interpreted as $O[(p\land \lnot p)\rightarrow Oq]$.